# Field having multiple attributes

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, toolbar, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

How to create fields having multiple attributes(each Field containing multiline texts,image icon,date etc) in an Application.??
What exactly they are called as???

Answer (score 2):

In the BlackBerry Java UI framework, the fundamental class is a `Field`.  A `Field` might be a `TextField` or `BitmapField` or `ButtonField`.

### Managers

If you want to create a field that is a group of fields, you would normally use or create a class that *extends* `Manager`.  A [Manager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html) is a container of field objects, that is responsible for properly laying out (sizing and positioning) the fields it contains.

Also, a `Manager` is itself a `Field` in that it extends `Field`.  So, you can have a heirarchy of field objects, and managers.  A `Manager` can contain child `Manager` objects, which themselves contain low-level fields: buttons, labels, sliders, etc.

You can extend the `Manager` class yourself, [and implement the methods to properly size and layout its children](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-custom-layout-manager-for-a-screen/ta-p/442990),

```java
protected abstract void sublayout(int width, int height);
public int getPreferredWidth();
public int getPreferredHeight();
```

or you can use one of the pre-written RIM managers, like `VerticalFieldManager`, or `HoriztonalFieldManager`.

`VerticalFieldManager`, for example, lays out all `Field` objects that you `add()` to it, in order, vertically from top to bottom.  You can adjust spacing on the child fields by calling `setMargin()` on each field.

Some other built-in `Manager` subclasses:

- `HorizontalFieldManager` - lays out child fields horizontally, in the order added, from left to right
- `FlowFieldManager` - lays out child fields horizontally, until horizontal space is full, and then vertically (like the words on a page *flow*)
- `AbsoluteFieldManager` - lays out child fields at fixed (x,y) screen coordinates
- `GridFieldManager` - lays out child fields in a grid of rows and columns ... like a table